# Error trying to deploy canvacord to herkou

Tags: javascript

sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied

The app compiles and works well locally, so i'm pretty sure it's something with the deployment settings.

Here is the full error:

```
   sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 126
   npm ERR! canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
   npm ERR! Exit status 126
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.6.1 install script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
   
   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.PnhI1/_logs/2020-08-01T15_10_47_770Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this wiki https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation:-Heroku for `node-canvas`/`canvacord` installation on Heroku.